# efficient way to program ajax with rows of record

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hi i have a table records which looks like this:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtTitle" class="txtTitle" value="Title 1" />
<input type="button" name="btnSaveTitle" class="btnSaveTitle" value="Save />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtTitle" class="txtTitle" value="Title 2" />
<input type="button" name="btnSaveTitle" class="btnSaveTitle" value="Save />
</td>
</tr>
.....
</table>
</form>
```

i like to save the records for the particular row in ajax POST. my current method is to get selected button clicked, and traverse backwards to get txtTitle value. for example:

```
$(".btnSaveTitle").click(function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    var txtTitle = selected.prev().val();
});
```

but if i were to have additional html tags around txtTitle, i would have to modify my javascript just to get txtTitle value. for example, if my html becomes this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
   <div class="textboxStyle">
   <input type="text" name="txtTitle" class="txtTitle" value="Title 2" />
   </div>
   <div class="btnStyle">
   <input type="button" name="btnSaveTitle" class="btnSaveTitle" value="Save />
   </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

then i have to modify my javascript to be this:

```
 $(".btnSaveTitle").click(function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    var txtTitle = selected.parent().prev().children("input:first").val();
 });
```

this is very hard to debug and error prone. how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var txtTitle = selected.closest("td").find(".txtTitle");
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JRmk/

Answer (score 1):

Well you know that they will always be in the same `td` (or possibly `tr`), so you can use

```
selected.closest("td").find("[type=text]")
```

If that's still no good for you, you can give the button and input the same attribute like `data-id` or something

```
<input type="text" data-id="1"
<input type="button" data-id="1"

txtTitle = $("[type=text][data-id=" + selected.data('id') + "]");
```